# System-wide SOCKS Proxy Settings?

Tags: network, macos, proxy, socks

If I have a SOCKS proxy running on a specific port, is there a way to configure all network traffic to leave through it?

If I configure the SOCKS proxy in the Network system preference, it seems to work properly for all browsers without additional configuration. (As reported by a quick Google for 'what is my IP' in both Chrome and Safari.)

However, a `traceroute` does not seem to be using this proxy, nor do downloads using `curl`. I also have no way of knowing whether other apps like Mail (SMTP) or an SSH connection are using the proxy.

I found the app MacProxy, but it's only a 30-day trial. It seems like there is surely a way to configure this via the command line for free?

Comment: are you running the SOCKS proxy with root privileges? That may fix your issue with `traceroute`, `curl` and other command line utilities. Just like you I am sure there is a "native" way of doing this but I am not sure how.  Probably with homebrew or another package manager.

Answer (score 1):

There could be a couple of things happening here. OS X support SOCKS v5 but your SOCKS server might still be on v4. The difference is that v5 also routes UDP through the proxy but v4 doesn't

Try `traceroute -I destination` which will make traceroute use ICMP echo instead of UDP and see if you get a different route.

`curl` should be using the proxy if you specify it. Try `curl --proxy socks5://proxyhost.examplecom:portnumber`